# Resources to learn Markov chains with memory or higher-order Markov chains

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains, markov-process

What are some beginner level resources to get introduced to [higher-order Markov chains or Markov chains with memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Variations)?

**Clarifying the context, in case it helps**. I was going through the [following paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=6df23d1e62e956d79b88e59f050c54d6b8257a2b), and in section 3.1 it became hard to follow the mathematics as I have never read anything about higher-order Markov chains. I want to get comfortable with the structure of the transition matrices, the stationary aspect of higher-order Markov chains etc.